# On Tab press throw error if textbox is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have registration screen which has username, password,verification code,email id etc.,. I need to do validation in jquery. The validation is if press Tab without entering any value in the username text box, it throw error message or some info to user saying that, the username should not empty. I am new jquery, done couple of validation, but it is not working correctly. Any suggestions? This is in MVC cshtml page.

MVC cshtml page

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Referenence_Cd, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "TxtReferenence_Cd" }, { "name", "Referenence_Cd" }, { "Class", "textBoxPlacHold" }, { "spellCheck", false }, { "maxLength", "13" } })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Authentication_Cd, new Dictionary<string, object> {{ "id", "TxtAuthentication_Cd" }, { "name", "Authentication_Cd" }, { "Class", "textBoxPlacHold" } ,{"spellCheck",false}, { "maxLength", "12" }})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Login_Id, new Dictionary<string, object> {{ "id", "Txtlogin" }, { "name", "Login_Id" }, { "Class", "textBoxPlacHold" }, { "jsValidation", "checkEMailAddr" } })
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new Dictionary<string, object> {{ "id", "txtPassword" }, { "name", "Password" }, { "Class", "textBoxPlacHold txtPassword" } })

Jquery: 
$('#TxtReferenence_Cd').blur(function () {
        if ($('#TxtReferenence_Cd').val() == "") {
            $('#spnVerificationErr').show();
            $('#spnVerificationErr').html("Reference number should not be empty!");
        }
        else{         
            $('#spnVerificationErr').hide();
            $('#spnVerificationErr').html("");
```

On tab press it need to show validation message, If i press tab without entering any value, it should show reference number should not be empty

Comment: just check the with the `blur` event

Comment: Ok.wil check with blur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('keydown', 'input', function(e) { 
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

  if (keyCode == 9) { 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    // show the message here
  } 
});
```

UPDATE:

you must be able to implement it in your own code, but anyway:

```
Jquery: 
$(document).on('keydown','#TxtReferenence_Cd',function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == 9) {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#spnVerificationErr').show();
            $('#spnVerificationErr').html("Reference number should not be empty!");
        }
        else{         
            $('#spnVerificationErr').hide();
            $('#spnVerificationErr').html("");
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: hi i have edited the question, can you pls look into that..and provide your suggestion

Comment: would you accept the answer if it is in fact what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out the answer myself.. Posted here for others whom it will help,

```
 $('#TxtReferenence_Cd').blur(function () {
            if ($('#TxtReferenence_Cd').val() == '') {
                $('#TxtReferenence_Cd').addClass('outLineRed');
                $('#spnVerificationErr').show();
                $('#spnVerificationErr').html("Reference number should not empty!");
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:White;");
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                return false;

            }
            else {
                $('#spnVerificationErr').hide();
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:#dfe5e6;");
                $('#TxtReferenence_Cd').removeClass('outLineRed');
            }
        }
            );

    $('#Authentication_Cd').blur(function () {
            if ($('#Authentication_Cd').val() == '') {
                $('#Authentication_Cd').addClass('outLineRed');
                $('#spnVerificationErr').show();
                $('#spnVerificationErr').html("Reference number should not empty!");
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:White;");
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                return false;

            }
            else {
                $('#spnVerificationErr').hide();
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:#dfe5e6;");
                $('#Authentication_Cd').removeClass('outLineRed');
            }
        }
            );


        $('#Txtlogin').blur(function () {

            if ($('#Txtlogin').val() == '') {
                $('#Txtlogin').addClass('outLineRed');
                $('#spnVerificationErr').show();
                $('#spnVerificationErr').html("Email address should not be empty!");
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:White;");
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                return false;

            }
            else {
                $('#spnVerificationErr').hide();
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:#dfe5e6;");
                $('#Txtlogin').removeClass('outLineRed');

            }

        }
            );


        $('#txtPassword').blur(function () {
            if ($('#txtPassword').val() == '') {
                $('#txtPassword').addClass('outLineRed');
                            $('#spnVerificationErr').show();
                            $('#spnVerificationErr').html("Password should not be empty!");
                            $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:White;");
                            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");

                return false;

            }
            else {
                $('#spnVerificationErr').hide();
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:#dfe5e6;");
                $('#txtPassword').removeClass('outLineRed');
            }

        }
        );
```